# How do I pass a numpy array to C++/SWIG using pointers without relying on numpy.i?

Tags: c++, python, arrays, numpy, matrix

Is there a way to pass a numpy array into C++/SWIG by just using a pointer to the first element?  I have a C++ function that anticipates a 3-by-N matrix, which is expected to be stored in column-major indexed contiguous memory.  Therefore, the function call takes the following parameters:

```
( double *mat3Xin, double *mat3Xout, int numTrip)
```

where numTrip is the N dimension of the matrix (i.e. number of triplets).  Since the input and inplace output is the same size, I do not require that to be passed in.  Is there a way to easily handle this in SWIG without using swig's renaming inline feature and creating a helper function which accepts the additional parameters swig's numpy interface requires for matrices?  I'm currently raveling the matrices in a helper function which then calls a renamed version of the original function, however, it is starting to get tedious to convert all the functions in my existing library to this form.

Thanks,

Comment: Getting the pointer is not the problem, but make sure that the array is c-contiguous first.

Comment: What do you mean by `numpy.i`?

Comment: `PyArray_DATA` gives you a pointer to element `0,0`.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this isn't possible and I am stuck with handwriting interfaces to these functions:
http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/swig.interface-file.html#a-common-example